# How to align Listbox Items left?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, listbox, alignment

Here is my asp.net codes

```
 <div class="output">
            <div class="listbox">

     <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="304px" Width="240px" ></asp:ListBox>

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="."></asp:Label>   
             <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server"  Height="100px" Width="240px"></asp:ListBox>
           </div>      
             </div>
```

and here css style

```
.listbox {
    width: 100%;       
}

 .output{
    background-color:rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.71);
    border: 2px solid grey;
    width: 270px;
    height: 540px;   
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:60%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;    }
```

I dont know why but on page inspecter it is left but on google chrome always aligned right.I have deleted history on chrome and check my code but couldnt find solution

[image]

Comment: did you clear the cache in chrome..? try that as well..

Comment: I did it . I cleared the cache

Comment: `And.....?` what are the results..?

Comment: Have you tried to specify `text-align: left;`? Could you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: cleargng cache didnt help.and then i also added text-align my code which is also not changing anything
.listbox {
   text-align: left;
    width: 100%;       
}

Comment: and here is cs code I also thought about here might be problem but couldnt find anything wrong;         ListBox3.Items.Add(String.Format("Number of Paragpraph: {0}", m));
         foreach (var item in results)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} occured {1} times", item.Word, item.Count));

Comment: you should use float:left;

Comment: I tried float:left didnt work. but default is already left i guess

Comment: It is because of your *output* class, because of it's *left* property

Comment: I have deleted output class to see if there is change,but nothing has changed